# Why does ConditionalFreqDist not work in NLTK?

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    (target,fileid[:4])
    for target in ['america']
    for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
```

It works fine, but I don't know why the samples got 1 in every file?

Comment: What's your error message? There's a closing parenthesis missing in your second example.

Comment: Also, in the first example you are counting how many times "america" and "citizen" appear in all those inaugural files. In the second example, you count how many files contain the "america"/"citizen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the FreqDist. It's about what you feed it – you need to know how the [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) work.

In your case it's a two-way nested generator. Look at it like a `for` loop:

```
for target in ['america']:
    for fileid in inaugural.fileids():
        # do something with target and fileid
```

In this case, the "do something" part is simply adding a pair of strings to the FreqDist. The string pairs look like this:

```
('america', <prefix_of_file_1>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_2>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_3>)
...
```

The first element is always the same, because you have just one item in the target list. The second element is made of the first 4 characters of the file ID. **You get exactly one entry per file,** regardless of whether 'america' is in the file or not, because you don't look at the content of the file, you just iterate over file IDs.

The way to do it is like the first example in your original post, before you deleted it:

```
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    (target, fileid[:4])
    for target in ['america']
    for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
    for w in inaugural.words(fileid)
    if w.lower().startswith(target))
```

Let's have a look at this *three*-way nested generator expression, written as `for` loops:

```
for target in ['america']:
    for fileid in inaugural.fileids():
        for w in inaugural.words(fileid):
            if w.lower().startswith(target)):
                # add target and fileid[:4] to the FreqDist
```

So here you iterate over **all words** (inner-most loop) in every file (middle loop), and you do for every target (first loop; here there is just one so there's not much looping). And then you skip all words that do not start with "america".

For example, let's say file 1 has two occurrences of "America" (or "American"), the second file has no mention of the target, and the third file has 3 occurrences. Then the pairs added to the FreqDist will look like this:

```
('america', <prefix_of_file_1>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_1>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_3>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_3>)
('america', <prefix_of_file_3>)
...
```

So for every occurrence of the target, you give the FreqDist an entry to count. Files without an occurrence are not counted, and multiple occurrences are counted multiple times.

Comment: You should go a step further and rewrite the loop so that it does not reread the whole corpus for each target word.

Comment: That's definitely what I would do too – you can even save a `for` loop by providing `str.startswith()` with a tuple of the targets. I was just trying to explain the (previously) given code, not suggest better code.